# Why does BottomAppBar must be child of CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

In all the samples and on the [Material Design website](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom/android#bottom-app-bar) `BottomAppBar` is used as a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`. I have read this is the recommended practice. I have tried it as a direct child of `ConstraintLayout` and it works fine. Why is this recommended? What is the purpose of wrapping it up in `CoordinatorLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` is similar to `RelativeLayout`, it provides a flexible way to create a flat hierarchy view. The main principle is to help in [relatively positioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#RelativePositioning) its child views. But this layout will not help you much in handling the animations and interactions between the parent and child views.

`CoordinatorLayout` is introduced as a top-level layout that helps in handling and animating the transitions of its views with some [behavior motions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior) defined for them.

> I have tried it as a direct child of ConstraintLayout and it works fine.

Yes, you can place `BottomAppBar` in `ConstrintLayout` also. But it will work as a normal child view without any motion behavior.

> Why is this recommended? What is the purpose of wrapping it up in CoordinatorLayout?

It is recommended because to help you with the view transitions and motion behavior of the `BottomAppBar`.

Comment: Please fix the typo in the first line "is similar to"